# Typescript transpiler: casing issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I have a typescript file that used to be called Group.ts. When transpiling to javascript the resulting file would be called Group.js.

I've now renamed the typescript file to group.ts (lowercase g). However, the resulting javascript file is still called Group.js (uppercase g). Even after removing Group.js and Group.js.map files.

I've tried renaming the typescript file to somegroup.ts and then the transpiled file was called somegroup.js (with correct casing). Then I renamed the file back to group.ts and the resulting javascript file is once again called Group.js (wrong casing).

Did anyone experience the same issue? Btw, I'm working on a Mac in case that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `/// <reference path="Group.ts" />` directive in some file (look closer to the 'root' of your compilation as the first name is the one that is used). The compiler, when faced with multiple spellings of the same name, has to arbitrarily pick one.

You can use the `--forceConsistentCasingInFileNames` commandline switch to more easily diagnose which file is in error.

Comment: I'm using Angular 2 and I had `import {Group} from "./Group";` instead of `import {Group} from "./group";` which is kind of the same thing as what you are saying. Thanks! :-)